# Sliding drawer with menu and functions

Tags: android, menu, slidingdrawer

I am working on a video editing app and on my Wildfire the camera app uses a sliding drawer for image adjustments, but it doesn't only list the options (as icons) but when you tap an icon the actual functions or adjustments that you can make are also part of the sliding drawer (see image).

[Sliding Drawer Android Wildfire http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/571/img0431zz.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/571/img0431zz.jpg)

I was wondering if I also could do that in my app and what I would need to do for that. If someone can help me out or maybe knows a tutorial for this, that would be great.

Thank you.

---

I am still working on the above but I have a problem with my slider and the icons...what happens is that when I tap the slider to close the drawer again everything disappears. (see below)

Slider open: [alt text http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/2087/screenshotslidingdrawer.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/2087/screenshotslidingdrawer.png)
Slider closed: [alt text http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/2087/screenshotslidingdrawer.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/2087/screenshotslidingdrawer.png)

I don't really know what I may have done wrong...

This is what I have been doing so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_background_gradient"
                  >

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="240px"
            android:layout_height="180px"
            android:id ="@+id/VideoViewEdit"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
        </VideoView>
        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/VideoViewEdit">
            <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="0">
                <TableRow
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_track_background"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        >
                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/ic_editor_videotrack"
                               android:padding="5px"
                               android:layout_gravity="left"/>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_track_background"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        >
                        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/ic_editor_audiotrack"
                               android:padding="5px"
                               android:layout_gravity="left"/>


                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_track_background"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        >
                    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/ic_editor_add_media"
                               android:padding="5px"
                               android:layout_gravity="left"
                               />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
 <SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/slider_handle"
         />

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button_exposure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_slider_exposure"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button_properties"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_slider_properties"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button_special_effects"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_slider_special_effects"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button_test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_slider_exposure"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button_test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#77000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_slider_exposure"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

     </LinearLayout>
 </SlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What part are you having trouble with?  The drawer or the settings?  For the setting check out [view stubs](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html), if it's the drawer you're struggling with try [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Comment: I am struggling with the part to set up a menu of icons that opens its functions within the slidingdrawer

Comment: That's where the view stubs come in.  Just have a `List` or `LinearLayout` with a view stub next to it so you can populate the stub when the user clicks an item in the list.

Comment: I ran into a problem...my slider and the icons disappear when I tap it for closing...

Comment: So before you open the drawer you see a handle on the side and once you close it you don't?

Comment: yes, exactly!

The handle and its content are still there, I just cannot see it. I accidentally tapped the correct position of the slider and it opened again (visible), but as soon as I close it, it disappears...

Comment: could something be wrong with the VideoView and the SlidingDrawer because the part that is not above the VideoView is visible yet the rest disappears...it seems that when I close the slider the, it goes under the VideoView...

Comment: You could try calling `bringToFront()` on the drawer or there may be a way to set the z-order of the children of the `RelativeLayout` to ensure that the `VideoView` is always under the drawer.

Comment: I tried bringToFront() on the drawer which unfortunately shows no result :(
what do you mean with setting the z-order? Is there anything that I could do programmatically or via XML to set the z order?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Try checking out the documentation for RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the magic: set drawer's background to #00000000!